# Check if session doesn't exist php

Tags: session, php

I have the following php code :

```
<?php 
if (!(session_id('password')) || !(session_id('user_name'))) {    
    header("Location: ../../"); /* Redirect browser */
}
 ?>
```

Which should check if session doesn't exist, and if it doesn't, the user redirects, the problem is that this condition is always true, even when the session does exists, my question is how can I fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try with `$_SESSION` like

```
<?php 
   if (!isset($_SESSION) || !isset($_SESSION['password']) || !isset($_SESSION['user_name'])) {
         header("Location: ../../"); /* Redirect browser */
   }
?>
```

Comment: No we can first check for session exists or not then we check for password and username

Comment: You are triggering notices if there is no password or username in the session. That's bad. Also, the logic is to redirect if they are not present.

Comment: It's nearly right in the question, besides the misuse of `session_id()`.

Answer (score 6):

`session_id()` is not used to fetch session information. It is used to change the user's session ID. What you have done is changed everyone's session ID to the string "user_name".

Instead do this;

```
if( empty( $_SESSION[ 'user_name' ] ) ) header("Location: ../../");
```

I wouldn't recommend storing the user's password in the session. There is no reason to and it's just safer to leave it out.

Answer (score 0):

1. check if you have started session on that page or not ?

use `session_start();` at the top of page..

1. with your if condition just add:

`if( isset($_session) && ...);`

1. session_id() is used to generate a session id not to check session variable.

so use `$_SESSION['username'] && $_SESSION['password']`

1. passing password in session is highly discourages.