# how can i check whether the session set or not from the header view

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

i want to check whether the session set or not. instead of checking in all the pages i want to check this in a view called header.php which is included in all files

my header view code is

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container-fluid" style="background: #1A7A7B">
    <div class="navbar-header float-left">
        <a href="http://www.rafeeque.zaliyo.in/smp1/index.php/admin/admin_home"><h2 align="center" style="float:left;">School Management System</h2></a>

        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".user-collapse">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>

    </button>
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".menu-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>

    </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse user-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right navbar-collapse">
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user ">Profile</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off">Logout</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</nav>
```

how to do this. thanks in advance

Comment: `if (isset($_SESSION[...]))`

Comment: This might be able to help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18286972/check-if-session-doesnt-exist-php

Answer (score 1):

You can check for a session, like this;

```
if ( $this->session->userdata('whatever') )
{
    // Do whatever you need...
}
```

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Answer (score 0):

Create new file, called `checkSession.php`. Write this code (modify for your needs)

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['foo'])) {
    $foo = $_SESSION['foo'];
} else {
    $foo = null;
}
```

In every page now you need to include this file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php include('checkSession.php'); ?>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set a session for validation purpose, you can use this

```
<?php 
if ($this->session->flashdata('notice')) 
{
    $data = $this->session->flashdata('notice');
    $class_str = $data['code'] === 0
        ? 'class = "alert alert-error"'
        : 'class = "alert alert-success"'; 
?>
    <div <?=$class_str?>>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
        <?=$data['message'];?>
    </div>
<?php
    }
?>
```

or otherwise for userdata:

```
if ($this->session->userdata('data'))
{
    //code
}
```